# How to echo results of this MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my code:

```
include_once("config.php");                   
$database = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$findnextsite = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM scraped_data";
echo $findnextsite;
$database->close();
```

Copy of my config.php file:

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "my_database");
define("DB_USER", "my_username");
define("DB_PASS", "password");
```

The above code is displaying this when I refresh the page:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM scraped_data
```

I'm trying to get it to display to results of the query, not the query itself.  Basically all I'm trying to do is find the highest `id` in my table and assign it to a variable to I can use it in a few places.

Comment: Are those the actual, literal contents of your config.php file, or a set of placeholders so as to avoid displaying the actual contents?

Comment: Be careful about using max unless you know what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$records=mysql_query($findnextsite );
**while($scraped_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
echo $Schools['Name'];**
}//end while
?>
```

Try using this piece of code for Echo.

Comment: make sure you're using ```mysqli_*``` commands as the ```mysql_*``` ones have been depreciated and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to execute the query first, store the results in a variable, and then echo that variable.  Right now you are echoing the literal value of the query string, rather than the value of results obtained by executing the query.

As per this page:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php try something like this...:

```
  if ($result = $database->query($findnextsite)) {
    echo $result;
  }
```